# Why is the terminal sending a CR even though ICRNL is set?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, tty, newlines

I have a terminal with the `bash` shell.

The terminal has the `ICRNL` flag set (so when the terminal sends a `CR`, it will be translated to `LF`, and then the `LF` will be sent to `bash`):

[image]

But I did a test that showed that `bash` will receive `CR` and not `LF`. Why is that?

*The test I made is running `hexdump` in another terminal and make it read what the first terminal is sending.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run `stty -a` from the bash prompt, you see the terminal settings while bash is not reading a command line.

When bash is reading a command line, it changes some terminal settings, including `icrnl` (turned off, because bash wants raw input since it does its own input processing). Bash restores the original settings before running the command.

To see what the terminal settings are at the bash prompt, note which terminal this is, and run `stty` from another terminal. For example:

1. In one terminal:

   ```
   bash-4.2$ tty
   /dev/pts/3
   bash-4.2$
   ```
2. In another terminal:

   ```
   $ stty -a </dev/pts/3
   … -icrnl …
   ```