# How to enable/disable stty settings?

Tags: stty

I'm on linux using bash with GNOME Terminal.
I used the command `stty -ixon` and then I checked if ctrl-s was sending XOFF and ctrl-q was sending XON : they weren't.
The problem is that by using `stty -ixoff` I can't re-enable the functions that these key combinations had.

Comment: I noticed that the reset command does that but it obviously also clears the screen, this is not exactely what I wanted.

Comment: Not only is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367081/ a related question, it is almost certainly the same answer.

Comment: @JdeBP I misunderstood the meaning of -ixon I thought it was an option and that -ixoff was the option that did the opposite, but now I know that by doing stty -ixon I disable XON and by doing stty ixon I enable it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set or clear the configuration flags you should use the following syntax:

```
stty -F /dev/yourdevice
```

Use `-` next to the name of the flag to clear it and remove `-` to set the flag On again. For example:

- `stty -F /dev/stty0 -parodd` to enable the even parity flag and
- `stty -F /dev/stty0 parodd` for odd parity.

Now replace the `parodd` flag of the example above for the flag you need to configure. You can check this [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html)

You can use the `stty -F /dev/ttyS0 sane` to reset some of the default values,
Remember that the device will reset the default values after a system reboot.