# changing/modifying terminal parameters general uses

Tags: linux, stty

I am learning about being able to change terminal parameters on red hat Linux, what are some professional applications in which this could be useful? Is this a common thing to do?

I am considering functions found on man stty

Comment: what parameters are you talking about?

Comment: modifying the terminal in general, such as changing the terminate program signal to another key, or removing it completely

Answer (score 0):

I don´t have enough reputation points but may be this question can be helpful
[How to enable/disable stty settings?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492307/how-to-enable-disable-stty-settings/670042#670042)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/390090)

Answer (score 0):

`stty` is used to set parameters for serial communication.

In the old, old days, every manufacturers' serial terminals could have different speeds ("Baud rate"), bits per character, parity, duplex, character encoding, ..., If you got any of these wrong, serial communication would not work.

It's easier to communicate with strange devices (GPS reciever, "dumb" sensors, etc) via serial interfaces, than by requiring networking.

`stty` helps.

GUI environments, running terminal emulators, don't use serial communication, and find `stty` less useful.